# Getting "JSONObject["loginInfo"] not found" error on trying to login using Jira rest client sdk

Tags: jira-rest-java-api

We are using Jira rest client sdk(jira-rest-java-client-api-2.0.0-m31.jar and jira-rest-java-client-core-2.0.0-m31.jar) for login and fetching data from Jira. Till friday morning(12th May,2017) we were able to login to Jira using mentioned Jira sdk(We have been using this sdk since last 1.5-2 years without any issue). But for some reason it started giving below error/exception when we try to login using same sdk:

```
    RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.absent(), errorCollections=[]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:47)
    at com.jira.JiraLogin.main(JiraLogin.java:21)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.absent(), errorCollections=[]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$3.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:181)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$3.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:175)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:12)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["loginInfo"] not found.
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:454)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.json.SessionJsonParser.parse(SessionJsonParser.java:33)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.json.SessionJsonParser.parse(SessionJsonParser.java:26)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$1.handle(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:138)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$3.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:179)
    ... 26 more
```

Below is sample piece of code(Java code) which we are using to login to Jira using sdk:

```
package com.jira;

import java.net.URI;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Session;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;

public class JiraLogin {
    private static final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory FACTORY = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String url = "https://mycompany.atlassian.net";
        String username = "hjethava";
        String email = "hjethava@xyzcompany.com";
        String password = "xxxxx";

        try {
            URI serverURI = new URI(url);
            JiraRestClient jrc = FACTORY.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(serverURI, email, password);
            Session s = jrc.getSessionClient().getCurrentSession().claim();
            username = s.getUsername();
            System.out.println("User '" + username + "' logged in successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help us here?